# Unable to sending complex object through WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a ServiceContract as such :

```
    bool CreateSlideshow(Slideshow current, string path, string name);
```

When I run my program calling the service, I get the following exception :

> *There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempura.org/:current. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry' with data contract
>   name
>   'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System'
>   is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any
>   types not known statically to the list of known types.....*

Apparently the problem lies in `Slideshow`. My class `Slideshow` has the following members :

```
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private List<Slide> slides;
```

and the class `Slide` has the following members :

```
    private String title;
    private ContentTypeEnum contentType;
    private String textContent;
    private String pictureContextPath;
```

where `ContentTypeEnum` is an enumeration.

Any idea how to resolve the exception? Hope for some advice/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just hope your classes have got public members

Comment: Consider posting your source code as one complete entry. It makes spotting problems much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your used types have to be marked with the `[DataContract]` attribute. The properties have to be marked with the `[DataMember]` attribute.

Furthermore your fields should be public properties, because a datacontract doesn't make any sense with private fields only.

```
[DataContract]
public class Slideshow
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Path { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Slide> Slides { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Slide
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ContentTypeEnum ContentType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String TextContent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String PictureContextPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, actually all my fields have a public getter and setter respectively. And I already put the [DataMember] attribute on all these fields, even the getter/setters (out of desperation)... Still same error message. Is it because there is a List in the class, or an enum? I'm really confused...

Comment: Hmmm... somehow I managed to solve the issue. My Slideshow and Slide classes both inherit from a ViewModelBase class. Apparently that's causing the problem. Once it was removed, all works fine. But anyway, thanks for your help. :)